# Postgresql auto-increment id's after restoring?

Tags: postgresql

I imported all tables from MySQL to PostgreSQL but now I have problems with id's.

The way I converted my MySQL DB was simple exported DB and copied all "INSERTS" with edited syntax, import was successful because I can see all 
 the data correct.

```
SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "elements_pkey"
DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

Is there any way to fix issues with id's?

Comment: You need to alter the primary key sequence to start at max(id)+1.
See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-altersequence.html

Comment: @Hitobat is this safe way?

Answer (score 1):

It works after reset the sequence.

```
SELECT setval('my_sequence_name', (SELECT max(id) FROM my_table));
```